# Why is this only applying the format to column A instead of the selected column J

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to alternate the alignment of a column to make reading a little easier, but even though im specifying the column J it always applies the formatting to column A

If i create a new sheet and run this against a simple 1 column sheet, it works great and as expected. But i need it to run against column J

```
Sub alternateAlignLeft()
    Columns("J:J").Select
    For rowx = 2 To 1000 Step 2
    Cells(rowx, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Next
End Sub


Sub alternateAlignRight()
    Columns("J:J").Select
    For rowx = 1 To 1000 Step 2
    Cells(rowx, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Next
End Sub
```

I need this code, which works great against column A, to work only for column J. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `Cells(rowx, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight` is referring directly to row rowx, column 1. Not within your selection, within your worksheet. If you want it to work in column J, change it to `Cells(rowx, 10)` (10 references the 10th column, or J)

Comment: so do i even need the Columns("J:J").Select line? seems like i dont

Comment: You are correct, the entire select line isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally try to avoid `.Select` as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Try this code:

```
Sub alternateAlignLeft()
For rowx = 2 To 1000 Step 2
    Cells(rowx, "J").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Next
End Sub

Sub alternateAlignRight()
For rowx = 2 To 1000 Step 2
    Cells(rowx, "J").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
Next
End Sub
```

To explain: `Cells` takes two arguments: `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex`. So you performed your formatting on column 1, which is column `A`. The `.Select` statement which came before actually doesn't affect this line at all as there is no reference to `Selection`.

Note that you should also qualify all your `Range` objects, like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowx, "J").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
```

This needs to be adjusted to your use case of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Columns("J:J").Select` isn't having any effect because you are then selecting the specific cell with:

```
 Cells(rowx, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

The `Cells(rowx, 1)` means the cell on row "rowx" in column 1... which is A.

If you want it to be J, you will need to change it to 10:

```
Cells(rowx, 10).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

and

```
 Cells(rowx, 10).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
```